# Cannot find module react-scripts

Tags: reactjs, installation, package.json, react-scripts

In package.json file I have these scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "server": "json-server --watch db.json --port 5000",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "client-build": "npm run-script build --prefix client",
    "chat": "nodemon index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "build": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client-build\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

And I use the "npm run dev" command to run server and client at the same time.
The server runs, but an error occurs with the client:

```
react-scripts start
[1]
[1] node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051
[1]   throw err;
[1]   ^
[1]
[1] Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\ehsan\Desktop\PDEI\Taghvim\sogo_react_20231127\client\node_modules\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
[1]     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
[1]     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
[1]     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
[1]     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
[1]   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
[1]   requireStack: []
[1] }
[1]
[1] Node.js v20.9.0
```

I cleared the npm cache, deleted and reinstalled the node_modules folder, even installed the react-scripts package separately, but none of it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is several solution to start your application.

1. Run `npm run build` first, and do `npm run start`
2. You might need to install the package `npm i react-scripts`
3. If you are on window machine, replace your capital "i" `I` in your project path into something different.

Answer (score 0):

you have to go into the node modules folder and rewrite the location of the scripts its strange i had that issue before, im pretty confident thatll fix you up

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).